# QGIS - create shapemap with region polygons from flatfile containing us zip to region assignments

Tags: qgis

I'm new to QGIS and I hope that you can help me with my issue. I have a csv file containing the US zip codes, their latitude / longitude and a Region (Q1 - Q6). For my Dashboard tool I'd like to create a shapefile in GeoJSON, where the zip codes are merged into the 6 regions.

Is there any easy way to achieve this in QGIS, e.g. create layers based on a specific attribute?

Comment: Zip codes can be found here: https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2016&layergroup=ZIP+Code+Tabulation+Areas  - start there and see about joining your CSV to the ZIP shapefile and then poking around your data and see that you can symbolize your zip codes by the REGION field ... from there you have a few options on how you can create a new dataset from those joined tables...